# Jquery :How did i get The number of images

Tags: jquery

I have a question about this, my "images" have aaa.jpg ,bbb.jpg",ccc.jpg" three images. 
What code did i use can get the "images" have three image?

```
   var images = [
        "aaa.jpg",
        "bbb.jpg",
        "ccc.jpg"
        ];
```

Comment: Are you looking for `images.length` ?

Comment: Right!!! very thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`images` here is an array, and arrays in JavaScript come built in with a [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) which we can use to determine the number of keys:

```
var numberOfImages = images.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `images.length` to get the array length.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```
var noOfImages = images.length
```

Comment: @dystroy it is a wiki edit

Answer (score 0):

`images.length` which will give you the length of the array (number of images)